# Running hadolint (Dockerfile linter) with Google Cloud Build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cloudbuild.yaml, hadolint

I'm working on image factory hosted on GCP and one of the pipeline I'm working on should build docker images from Dockerfile that is pushed to Cloud Source Repository.
As a step 0 in my cloud build pipeline I'd like to use hadolint to check the Dockerfile. The aim is to use a hadolint.yaml config file to alter default hadolint behaviour. Here is the code of the step:

```
    steps:
  # Validating Dockerfile syntax
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['-c', 'docker run --rm -i -v ./hadolint.yaml:/.config/hadolint.yaml hadolint/hadolint < Dockerfile']
```

Unfortunately, it does not work:

```
Step #0: docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: './hadolint.yaml:./config/hadolint.yaml': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: './config/hadolint.yaml' mount path must be absolute.
Step #0: See 'docker run --help'.
```

hadolint.yaml file is in the same root location in the same repository as the Dockerfile.

It seems working perfectly fine when i run this command from the command line locally!

```
(GCP-project)$ docker run --rm -i hadolint/hadolint < Dockerfile
-:3 SC2034 warning: unzip appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
(GCP project)$ docker run --rm -i -v ./hadolint.yaml:/.config/hadolint.yaml hadolint/hadolint < Dockerfile
(GCP Project)$
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?